# Problems installing Snack for Python on Mac

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to install the package tkSnack (http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/) for Python on my Mac computer.

I downloaded the package, ran the "setup.py" file and got no error messages. However, when I try to initalize as below, I get an error message:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

import tkSnack
tkSnack.initializeSnack(root)
```

I get the error message after typing in the last line:

```
>>> from Tkinter import *
>>> from tkSnack import *
>>> root = Tk()
>>> tkSnack.initializeSnack(root)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "tkSnack.py", line 21, in initializeSnack
    Tkroot.tk.call('eval', 'package require snack')
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package snack
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
Added the output after running the setup.py-file:

```
Fredriks-MacBook-Air:python Fredrik$ sudo python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
copying tkSnack.py -> build/lib
running install_lib
byte-compiling /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tkSnack.py to tkSnack.pyc
running install_egg_info
Writing /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tkSnack-2.2.9-py2.7.egg-info
Fredriks-MacBook-Air:python Fredrik$
```

Comment: Did you run `python setup.py install`?  Did you get any output?

Comment: Yes. I ran the setup.py file (as I said in the post). No error messages. I've added the output.

Comment: What version of Tcl/Tk do you have? Find out using import Tkinter; 
Tkinter.Tk().tk.eval('info tclversion') According to [this page](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/pyinstall.html), you need to have the same version of Tcl/Tk and Snack. Also, Macs have some issues with Tcl/Tk. Read [this page](http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/)

Comment: Also, what version of Python are you using?